# Single adjective meaning "for a long time"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Basically I want to say:

> Sheep grazing is one of the possible ways to restore the biodiversity
>   of alpine meadows *that have been uncultivated for a long time*.

But I would like to form much nicer and simpler sentence. I would imagine something like this:

> Sheep grazing is one of the possible ways to restore the biodiversity
>   of [THAT WORD] uncultivated alpine meadows.

So I am looking for a single word that would beam "for a long time" which could be placed there to make the sentence more fluent :-)

The only thing I can think of is "longly" but this sounds suspicious to me :-)

Comment: "Fallow" would have been a good choice. It conveys both a sense of time and "previously-but-no-longer-cultivated". Although I'd still use "long" as in "the biodiversity of the long-fallow alpine meadows". It also can insinuate that cultivation will resume later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**long**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/long) itself works perfectly fine as an adverb

> For a long time:
>
> *his long-awaited Grand Prix debut*

long-uncultivated alpine meadows, though it sounds a bit unusual, should do it.

Comment: Or better still, "that have **long** been uncultivated" ?

Comment: Because *long uncultivated* sound awkward, that adjective form generally goes with positives, not negatives. *Long neglected* works, *long uncared* doesn't I think.

Answer (score 1):

How about "... that have long been uncultivated"? No-one will think you're referring to a distance so there's no room for confusion.

Comment: not so elegant.. I'd like to get rid of "... that have ..." subsentence...

Answer (score 0):

> Sheep grazing is one of the possible ways to restore the biodiversity of **long-term** uncultivated alpine meadows.

Comment: really? Can the word "long-term" actually serve as an adjective in this context? This is new to me.

Comment: Yes, I think you could use long-term in this way.

Comment: "Long-term uncultivated" can be understood as short for "uncultivated in the long term". Technically, *long-term* is ambiguous about referring to the past, the future, or both. But the given context resolves this ambiguity sufficiently.

Comment: What about this?  Sheep grazing is one possible way to restore the biodiversity of alpine meadows long out of cultivation.